# Definition of Regular Representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

I have troubles understanding the following definition. I post two pictures of the same definition, one is of my notes.

### Definition - Regular Representation

[image]

---

[image]

In my notes, in the second picture, there are two ways of seeing the same thing. The first just consider the representation as a group action. But then I am asking myself why the map should be in $GL(\oplus_{h\in G}K)$. How one can just come to such a notation? How am I supposed to see it? And for the proper one, which looks more appropriate, can I consider $x\in K$?
Can some one explain me what is it meant with this definition? What is the intuition behind this? Thank you so much in advance :)

Comment: Why the map should be in GL? Well, this is really by definition.  If you have a finite set $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$, then you can extend it linearly to a vector space $V = K$-span$\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ with basis $X$.  Since $G$-action on $X$ means that $g(x)\in X$ for all $x\in X$, so for any $v\in V$, we have $g(v) = g(\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i x_i)$ which is by definition $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i g(x_i)$ and hence is back in $V$.  Since group has inverse, and a representation is a homomorphism, so the transforamtion represented by $g$ is invertible, hence it is in GL.

Comment: And the regular representation is just to take $X=G$.  I don't understand what you mean by $x\in K$, and I am guessing you are confused by some notations.  Here $\bigoplus_{h\in G} K$ means the $|G|$-dimensional $K$-vectorspace with basis given by elements of $G$.

Comment: @Aaron Thanks.. I actually meant $x_h$ instead of $x$. Yes very confused :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $K$ is the field. When you write :

$$E:=\bigoplus_{h\in G}K $$

You should think of $E$ as a $K$-vectorial space which has a base indexed by $G$ : $\{e_h\mid h\in G\}$, $e_h$  spanning the $h$-th copy of $K$ in

$$E:=\bigoplus_{h\in G}K $$

Now we have an action of $G$ on the set $\{e_h\mid h\in G\}$, given by $g.e_h:=e_{gh}$. The claim (in the first notation) is that it allows you to define a representation $\rho$ in $GL(E)$ by simply defining that $\rho(g)$ will send $\sum_{h\in G}\lambda_he_h$ on  $\sum_{h\in G}\lambda_he_{gh}$. In other word $\rho(g)$ is defined by its image on a base (we just ask that $e_h$ be sent to $e_{gh}$) and then it defines a unique linear mapping because $\{e_h\}$ is a base.

For the second, $x\in K$ does not make sense to me.  You just need to realize that :

$$(\lambda_h)_{h\in H} \text{ is another notation for } \sum_{h\in G}\lambda_he_h $$

So that :

$$\rho(g)((\lambda_h)_{h\in H})=\rho(g)(\sum_{h\in G}\lambda_he_h)=\sum_{h\in G}\lambda_he_{gh}=\sum_{k\in G}\lambda_{g^{-1}k}e_{k}=\sum_{h\in G}\lambda_{g^{-1}h}e_{h}=((\lambda_{g^{-1}h})_{h\in H}) $$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)